# ggplot2: How to bring geom_text in front of bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, geom-text

I want to use `geom_text()` my graph but it is shown behind my bargraphs.

How can I bring it in front of the bars and how to show the total amount as `geom_text()` also?

you will find below my data set(edit)

```
 BRNCH_NAME PRODUCTS FINAL_SCORE
1   A ANCH  BILL    1998
2   B ANCH  BILL    1216
7   G ANCH  BILL    1220
8   H ANCH  BILL    1217
16  A ANCH  TICKET  1998
17  B ANCH  TICKET  2331
18  C ANCH  TICKET  0
19  D ANCH  TICKET  0
20  E ANCH  TICKET  0
21  F ANCH  TICKET  0
22  G ANCH  TICKET  1665
31  A ANCH  SHOP    2331
32  B ANCH  SHOP    1154
33  C ANCH  SHOP    1165
34  D ANCH  SHOP    1388
35  E ANCH  SHOP    1265
```

[image: my shown graph]

```
ggplot(data = FINAL_SCORE_BAR,
       aes(x = reorder(FINAL_SCORE_BAR$BRNCH_NAME, FINAL_SCORE_BAR$FINAL_SCORE),
           y = FINAL_SCORE, fill = PRODUCTS, label = FINAL_SCORE)) +
    geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
    labs(y = "HGA ALL FINAL SCORE", x = "ELEMENTS", face = "bold",
         colour = "black", csize = 5) +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold")) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

Comment: Those are two different questions: 1. *how can I bring it in front of bars* - just  move your `geom_text` code after `geom_bar`; 2. I can't understand what you want

Comment: Give us the example of you dataset if you want us to help you. Have you read [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and the answers on how to ask questions efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of your geoms, e.g.:

```
ggplot(data = FINAL_SCORE_BAR,
       aes(x = reorder(FINAL_SCORE_BAR$BRNCH_NAME, FINAL_SCORE_BAR$FINAL_SCORE),
           y = FINAL_SCORE, fill = PRODUCTS, label = FINAL_SCORE)) +
    labs(y = "HGA ALL FINAL SCORE", x = "ELEMENTS", face = "bold",
         colour = "black", csize = 5) +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold")) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
    # the order of geoms matters
    geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

---

**UPDATE** based on the updated information in the question.

---

Column "PRODUCTS" is missing in your data. Without it my answer is this (you should instal `data.table` and `tidyverse` packages if you don't have them:

```r
library(tidyverse)

FINAL_SCORE_BAR <- 
    data.table::fread(stringsAsFactors = TRUE,
'BRNCH_NAME ELEMENTS FINAL_SCORE
"A ANCH"  BILL    1998
"B ANCH"  BILL    1216
"G ANCH"  BILL    1220
"H ANCH"  BILL    1217
"A ANCH"  TICKET  1998
"B ANCH"  TICKET  2331
"C ANCH"  TICKET  0
"D ANCH"  TICKET  0
"E ANCH"  TICKET  0
"F ANCH"  TICKET  0
"G ANCH"  TICKET  1665
"A ANCH"  SHOP    2331
"B ANCH"  SHOP    1154
"C ANCH"  SHOP    1165
"D ANCH"  SHOP    1388
"E ANCH"  SHOP    1265')


FINAL_SCORE_BAR <- FINAL_SCORE_BAR %>% 
    mutate(BRNCH_NAME = reorder(BRNCH_NAME, FINAL_SCORE, FUN = mean))

my_sum <- FINAL_SCORE_BAR %>% 
    group_by(BRNCH_NAME) %>% 
    summarize(SUM_FINAL_SCORE = sum(FINAL_SCORE))

ggplot(data = FINAL_SCORE_BAR,
       aes(x = BRNCH_NAME, y = FINAL_SCORE)) +
    labs(y = "HGA ALL FINAL SCORE", x = "ELEMENTS", face = "bold",
         colour = "black", csize = 5) +
    coord_flip(ylim = c(0, 7500)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold")) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
    # The sums:
    geom_text(data = my_sum,
              aes(x = BRNCH_NAME,
                y = SUM_FINAL_SCORE,
                label = SUM_FINAL_SCORE),
              size = 3,
              hjust = -0.2,
              inherit.aes = FALSE
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this is work :) ı also add my dataset, how to show their total amount at the end of each bar .

Comment: I cant see where your data is. Are you sure you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4783029) *carefully*?

Comment: By the way, if you think, that the answer was helpful, consider upvoting it. If it is the answer you were looking for -- accept it.

Comment: I have already accept your answer furthermore i have two questions in my ticket now i try to show total amount of each line at the graph also.

Comment: Column "PRODUCTS" is missing in your data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as an update elements are products.Now i will update my post for further answers.

Comment: By the way scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") code is not working at your second update.

Comment: Because there is no fill in the example.